# Set clicklistener in recycler adapter to download video from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to set a button in recycler adapter which is fetching video from firebase so that user can download video into his mobile phone from firebase. Below is my firebase adapter code which i am using to fecth video from firebase.
I also tried various code from stackoverflow but I dont know why my suddenly crashes and gives me unkown errors. I am getting error- "neither user 10388 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. " . I have given all read and write storage permission in my Manifest file.

```
public class VideosAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<VideoItem , VideosAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    ImageButton download;   <------ Button to download video
    ImageButton share;      <------ Button for sharing video on other social media platforms

   
    public VideosAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<VideoItem> options) {
        super(options);
    }
 
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull VideoItem model) {
            holder.setdata(model);


download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(model.videoUrl));
                    request.setDescription("download");
                    request.setTitle(""+model.videoTitle);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    }
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, ""+model.videoTitle+".mp4");


                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    manager.enqueue(request);
                    
                    
                }
            });

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_container_video, parent, false);

        download = view.findViewById(R.id.download);  <------ i want to set clicklistener on this 
                         button to download video.
        share = view.findViewById(R.id.vidshare);


        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        VideoView videoView;
        TextView videoTitle;


        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            videoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoview);     <---- Displaying my videos in video view
            videoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textVideoTitle);


        }

        void setdata(VideoItem obj){
            videoView.setVideoPath(obj.videoUrl);   <---- accessing the url of my video
            videoTitle.setText(obj.videoTitle);
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
                mp.start();

            });

            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer::start);

        }
    }



}
```

---

Above was my firebase adapter code. I am using this adapter to fetch the video from firebase into recycler view and display it to user. I want to set buttons like those in TikTok app for sharing and downloading videos.

I have done all this via youtube tutorial. He only told how to fetch videos from firebase in recyclerview, but he did not told about setting buttons to it.

Comment: "*suddenly crashes and gives me unkown errors*" - your question to provide the exact error messages and a reference to the line of code that caused it.

Comment: Post the error log along with the question

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have updated my question and also give the error which i am getting along with the code that that I have used from stackoverflow to download videos.